# How one can dynamic_cast from std::exception to std::nested_exception?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, dynamic-cast, nested-exceptions

I've just seen a code containing  dynamic_cast from `std::exception` to `std::nested_exception`, for instance,

```
try {
    std::throw_with_nested(std::runtime_error("error"));
} catch (std::exception &e) {
    auto &nested = dynamic_cast<std::nested_exception&>(e);
    std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
}
```

At the very first time, I thought this code won't be compiled because `std::nested_exception` is **not derived** from `std::exception` and I expected `dynamic_cast` would do static check of inheritance but I was wrong.

Although I couldn't find related standard specification which explicitly mentions that `dynamic_cast` allows this, I confirmed that all three major compilers(clang/gcc/msvc) allow `dynamic_cast` between totally unrelated types.

But still, `std::nested_exception` is not derived from `std::exception`, so I thought the `dynamic_cast` will throw an `bad_alloc` exception and `"ok"` never printed. I was wrong again.

Now, I'm wondering how this can work. Is this a something special and exceptional for `std::exception` and `std::nested_exception`? Or, can I make another successful `dynamic_cast<A&>(b)` where type `A` and type of object `b` do not have common base class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> At the very first time, I thought this code won't be compiled because std::nested_exception is not derived from std::exception

That's not sufficient - `std::nested_exception` is intended to be used as a mixin class, like

```
struct MyExceptionWrapper: public std::exception, std::nested_exception
{
    // an 3rd-party component of my library threw
    // and I want to wrap it with a common interface
};
```

> expected dynamic_cast would do static check of inheritance but I was wrong

In the above case `dynamic_cast` has to check *at runtime* whether your `std::exception` is *really* a `MyExceptionWrapper`, in which case it *is also* a `std::nested_exception`.

This is why it is called *dynamic* cast, because it has to check the dynamic type at runtime. If you want to perform a static check at compile time, you're looking for *static* cast.

> Although I couldn't find related standard specification which explicitly mentions that dynamic_cast allows this

This is all [well documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). We're discussing the following clause from the linked page:

> > - 5) If expression is a pointer or reference to a polymorphic type Base, and new_type is a pointer or reference to the type Derived a run-time check is performed:

(note that `Base=std::exception` *is* polymorphic)

> > - - b) Otherwise, if expression points/refers to a public base of the most derived object, and, simultaneously, the most derived object has an unambiguous public base class of type Derived, the result of the cast points/refers to that Derived (This is known as a "sidecast".)

Since you can't tell at compile time that a `std::exception&` is not really a `MyExceptionWrapper`, you have to do this at runtime.

---

PS. if you want to avoid accidentally rethrowing inside a `catch` block, just write

```
auto *nested = dynamic_cast<std::nested_exception*>(&e);
```

instead. Then you can check for `nullptr` to find out whether it succeeded.

---

PPS. As Sean suggests, the `MyExceptionWrapper` above is really more likely to be a type generated by [`throw_with_nested`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/throw_with_nested), but it has the same effect.

Comment: This is a sidecast, not a downcast.

Comment: You're quite right, I pasted the wrong bullet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [std::throw_with_nested](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/throw_with_nested) states that the type thrown will publicly dervive from both [std::nested_exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception) **and** the type of the exception you pass in. So, in your example, the exception thrown conceptually has the type:

```
class some_exception : public std::nested_exception, public std::runtine_exception
{

};
```

And, as `std::runtime_exception` is derived from `std_exception` you are able to catch it.